# Mathematically rigorours formulation of the Bogoliubov transform for bosons

Tags: mathematical-physics, second-quantization

Let $\mathfrak{H}$ denote the Hilbert space describing the single-particle states and $|k\rangle$ denote an orthonormal basis of $\mathfrak{H}$. Let $c_k$ denote the corresponding annihilation operators on the Fock space $\mathfrak{F}$.

From [Bach Theorem 2.2](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02188656), I know that if $c_k$ are fermionic and $W:\mathfrak{H} \oplus \mathfrak{H} \rightarrow \mathfrak{H} \oplus \mathfrak{H}$ is unitary and of the form 
\begin{equation*}
W =
\begin{bmatrix}
u & v \\
\bar{v} & \bar{u}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
with $\text{tr} (vv^*) <\infty$ then there exists a unitary $\mathscr{W}: \mathfrak{F} \rightarrow \mathfrak{F}$ such that if $d^*_k \equiv \mathscr{W} c^*_k \mathscr{W^*}$, then $(d^*, d) = (c^*, c)W$ (in the sense of matrix multiplication)

Is there a similar rigorous formulation for bosons? Any references would be appreciated.